# How can I add a google maps marker to the map asynchronously?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

so I'm having a little issue which I just can't seem to solve and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have 2 functions.

One simply adds a google maps Marker to the map.

```
private void setMarker() {
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng)
            .snippet(artesao.getId())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
            .title(artesao.getName()));
}
```

The other, downloads an image from an URI, converts it into a bitmap and adds a canvas. I want to pass this image onto the setMarker() function once downloaded to replace the regular Google Maps Red Marker.

```
private void downloadMarker() {
    imageLoader.loadImage(artigo.getPhotoURL(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
            Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);

            Paint color = new Paint();
            color.setTextSize(35);
            color.setColor(Color.BLACK);


            canvas1.drawBitmap(loadedImage, 0,0, color);
            canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30, 40, color);
            img.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

            setMarker();
        }
    });
}
```

Most of the things in the function are irrelevant for this matter

This function will work and it will call the setMarker(), but the marker itself won't be added to the map, although everything else inside said function will work as expected. The image is also being loaded, as I've tested it with the img.setImageBitmap(bmp) you can see above

On the other hand, if I call the same setMarker() function outside of the imageLoader.loadImage() function but inside the downloadMarker() function, it will add the Marker.

I think this is due to the function being Asynchronous, but I really don't understand why that would be an issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `onLoadingComplete` called on the main thread? Any relevant statements in the logcat?

Comment: It's an asynchronous function, so probably not. Logcat doesn't return any errors. It just doesn't add the maker to the map.